# Android canvas.drawText() not showing

Tags: android, canvas

So, I have this problem where my android text drawn on a canvas on top of a background image is not showing. my code:

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    final float scaleFactorX = getWidth() / WIDTH;
    final float scaleFactorY = getHeight() / HEIGHT;

    if(canvas != null) {
        final int savedState = canvas.save();
        canvas.scale(scaleFactorX, scaleFactorY);

        Paint textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        textPaint.setTextSize(20);
        textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        canvas.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(button_start, (canvas.getWidth() - button_start.getScaledWidth(canvas)) / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 4, null);
        canvas.drawText("Test text", 0, 0, textPaint);
        canvas.restoreToCount(savedState);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: As a side note, avoid creating instances in onDraw(). Paint object can be reused, you're just wasting lots of memory here.

Comment: What's the purpose of `canvas.restoreToCount(savedState);`?

Comment: @cygery I thought that without it, the screen would keep rescaling, and thus keep zooming in. After testing, it seems that that is not the case. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

the y axis of base line is not 0, try this

```
    Paint textPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    textPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    textPaint.setTextSize((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
    textPaint.setTextAlign(Align.LEFT);
    FontMetrics metric = textPaint.getFontMetrics();
    int textHeight = (int) Math.ceil(metric.descent - metric.ascent);
    int y = (int)(textHeight - metric.descent);
    canvas.drawText("text", 0, y, textPaint);
```